# SSMA- Not migrating all the rows from oracle to sql via ssma

Tags: sql-server, migration, sql-server-migration-assi

I migrated data from Oracle to SQL Server, the rows count in Oracle is around 11487 rows, but when SSMA finished the migration "message said 99.7% rows processed" It was not 100%. Also, there is no error

```
Migrating data...
Analyzing metadata...
Preparing table myschema.users...
Preparing data migration package...
Starting data migration Engine
Starting data migration...
The data migration engine is migrating table '"sch"."my_USERS"': > [DB].[sch].[my_USERS], 256708 rows total
Table "sch"."my_USERS" data migration: 26000 rows processed.
Table "sch"."my_USERS" data migration: 52000 rows processed.
Table "sch"."my_USERS" data migration: 78000 rows processed.
Table "sch"."my_USERS" data migration: 103000 rows processed.
Table "sch"."my_USERS" data migration: 129000 rows processed.
Table "sch"."my_USERS" data migration: 155000 rows processed.
Table "sch"."my_USERS" data migration: 180000 rows processed.
Table "sch"."my_USERS" data migration: 206000 rows processed.
Table "sch"."my_USERS" data migration: 232000 rows processed.
Completing migration of table "sch"."my_USERS"...
Migration complete for table '"sch"."my_USERS"': > [DB].[sch].[my_USERS], 256610 rows migrated (Elapsed Time = 00:00:07:31:512).
Data migration operation has finished.
    0 table(s) successfully migrated.
    1 table(s) partially migrated.
    0 table(s) failed to migrate.
```

Preparing data migration package...
Starting data migration Engine
Starting data migration...
The data migration engine is migrating table '"sch"."my_USERS"': > [DB].[sch].[USERS], 256708 rows total
Table "sch"."my_USERS" data migration: 26000 rows processed.
Table "sch"."my_USERS" data migration: 52000 rows processed.
Table "sch"."my_USERS" data migration: 78000 rows processed.

1.

> `List item`

Table "sch"."my_USERS" data migration: 103000 rows processed.
Table "sch"."my_USERS" data migration: 129000 rows processed.
Table "sch"."my_USERS" data migration: 155000 rows processed.
Table "sch"."my_USERS" data migration: 180000 rows processed.
Table "sch"."my_USERS" data migration: 206000 rows processed.
Table "sch"."my_USERS" data migration: 232000 rows processed.
Completing migration of table "sch"."my_USERS"...
Migration complete for table '"sch"."my_USERS"': > [DB].[sch].[my_USERS], 256610 rows migrated (Elapsed Time = 00:00:07:31:512).
Data migration operation has finished.
0 table(s) successfully migrated.
1 table(s) partially migrated.
0 table(s) failed to migrate.

Comment: maybe rowcount changed under migration?

Comment: @siggemannen If you see the first line it says how many rows to be migrated. So, possibly not that reason

Comment: yeah, but it still could've changed in the meantime?

Comment: @siggemannen You are right but again the number will be more that the original but the migrated rows remains lesser than that

Comment: Upon digging down, found duplicate entries at source. After disabling dup key it was 100% migrated